# Gibbs-Duhem equation and homogeneous function of mixed Euler order

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, physical-chemistry, chemical-potential, electrochemistry

My question is related to this [article](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0013-4686(96)00209-5) by Sorensen and Compan. The usual definition of an homogeneous function of order $\mathcal M$ is by the equation $f(\lambda \mathbf{x}) = \lambda^{\mathcal M} f(\mathbf{x})$ where $\mathbf{x}= x_1,x_2, ..x_N$. In the context of thermodynamics $\mathbf{x}$ represents the set of extensive variables characterizing the internal energy $E=f(\mathbf{x})$. The underlying assumption is that if we proportionally scale the extensive parameters while keeping the intensives fixed the internal energy increases proportionally, i.e., $E$ is an order $\mathcal M=1$ homogeneous function. This works very well for, say, $x_0=S, x_1=V,x_2=\tilde n$, that is, entropy, volume, molar mass, etc.

A simple differentiation leads to the Gibb-Duhem law. Starting with $f(\lambda \mathbf{x}) = \lambda^{\mathcal M}f(\mathbf{x})$ take the differential of $f(\{X_k\}=f(\lambda\{x_k\})$
with respect to $\lambda$:
$$\frac{df}{d\lambda} = {\mathcal M}\lambda^{\mathcal M-1} f(\mathbf{x})= \sum_k \frac{\partial f}{\partial X_k}\frac{dX_k}{d\lambda}
=\sum_k \left[\frac{\partial f}{\partial X_k}\right]_{X_k=\lambda x_k} x_k$$
and it would also hold specifically for $\lambda = 1$ in which case we get
$${\mathcal M} f(\mathbf{x})=\sum_kp_k x_k \tag{1}\label{1}$$
with $$p_k=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_k}\tag{2}\label{2}$$ being the intensive parameter conjugate to the extensive $x_k$, and of course, then also $$df=\sum_k p_k dx_k \tag{4}\label{4}.$$

Now taking the differential of $\eqref{1}$ we get
$${\mathcal M} df(\mathbf{x})=\sum_k p_k dx_k + \sum_k x_k dp_k $$ and subtracting it from $\eqref{4}$ yields
$$({\mathcal M}-1)df = \sum_k x_k dp_k \tag{5}\label{5}$$

As I mentioned above, it is usually assumed that for the most common extensive parameters ${\mathcal M}=1$ and then we get from $\eqref{5}$ the Gibbs-Duhem equation according to which $$\sum_{k}^{({\mathcal M}=1)} x_k dp_k=0 \tag{6}\label{6}$$

But what about extensives whose contribution to the internal energy is not of homogeneous order ${1}$? For example, the potential energy of an elastic spring is homogeneous order $2$ because the elastic energy is proportional to the *square* of displacement $\frac{1}{2}k' \ell^2$, and similarly the electrostatic energy of condenser is $\frac{1}{2}c' q^2$ where $c'$ is the compliance (reciprocal of its capacitance), etc. In either case the conjugate intensive is a linear function of the displacement or charge: $p_{elastic} =k' \ell$, the tension, and $p_{electric}=c' q$, the voltage. For these cases ${\mathcal M}=2$ and then instead of the Gibbs-Duhem equation of $\eqref{6}$ we have from $\eqref{5}$ that

$$df= \sum_k^{{\mathcal M}=2} x_k dp_k=\sum_k^{{\mathcal M}=2} p_k dx_k \tag{7}\label{7}$$

Now in the referenced [article](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0013-4686(96)00209-5) Sorensen and Compan comment that we still get the Gibbs-Duhem equation at least *partially* if one can decompose the internal energy function into terms such $E=E^{(1)}+E^{(2)} +E^{(3)} +...$, where the terms $E^{(1)}$, $E^{(2)}$, $E^{(3)}$, etc., represent internal energies in which only $\mathcal M =1$, $\mathcal M =2$, $\mathcal M =3$, etc., dependence evolves independently from each other. The example they analyze in detail is the case of electrochemical potential for which they show that applying $\mu_{ec} = \mu_{c} + q \mathcal F \psi $ ($\mu_c$ is the chemical and $\psi$ is the electrostatic potential, $\mathcal F$ is the "Faraday" constant) in the Gibbs-Duhem equation is *wrong* for it mixes the energy of molar mass of order $1$ with the energy of electrostatic charge of order $2$ and they must be treated separately. They claim contrary to almost all textbooks that the Gibbs-Duhem equation holds with $\mu_c$ and not with $\mu_{ec}$.

While the mathematics is simple if the two Euler orders are separable but I am puzzled by their ability to sperate them because by my naïve view it would imply that there is no direct thermal (entropy) exchange related to electric charge exchange. How is that possible?

Comment: > *"it would imply that there is no direct thermal (entropy) exchange related to electric charge exchange"* I think that is due to that strong assumption that energy is sum of two energies and no mixing of variables in total energy expression. So the electrostatic system of 2nd order is independent of the rest of the system, like a capacitor put next to a jar of gas. If we had system where we're adding electrons to the gas, then internal energy probably would not be separable into sum of independent terms (1st order) + (2nd order).

Comment: @JanLalinsky this is exactly how I felt about after reading the article. If the processes are "that" much separable then there cannot be thermodynamic significance of the "separated" it has its own $2^{nd}$ "temperature" say, $T^*=\chi S$, that is *proportional* to $S$ with which it can "mix" its entropy and that of the rest. Do you know of any experiments clearly deciding which potential, chemical or electrochemical, is to be in used in the Gibbs-Duhem equation, or the latter does not even hold in any case for mixed Euler order contra everybody be it Gibbs or Guggenheim, etc .